# java.io.FileNotFoundException: "" at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:194)

Tags: android, post, httpurlconnection

I have an API to POST an image and other details to the server. I get `FileNotFoundException`. Please find the below code :

```
public int uploadFile(final String sourceFileUri) {

    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    Log.d("uploadFile","sourceFileURI:: "+sourceFileUri);
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile.getAbsoluteFile());

        URL url = new URL("http://samaya.apprikart.com/dd_api_v1/report_news/");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
        conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
        conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"news_title\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes("NEWS TITLE"); // mobile_no is String variable
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);

        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image_link\";filename=\""+ mSelectedImagePath + "\"" + lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

        bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
        bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
        buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

        bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

        while (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        }


        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

        serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
        String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

        Log.d("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "+ serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

        final StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line;
        while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(line);
            response.append('\r');
        }
        rd.close();
        Log.d("uploadFile", "response.toString(): "+response.toString());

        if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

            if (getActivity()!=null)
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                        Toast.makeText(mContext,
                                "Submitted Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .show();
                        if (getActivity()!=null)
                            getActivity().finish();
                    }
                });
        }else{
            Log.d("uploadFile", "error.toString(): "+conn.getErrorStream());
        }

        fileInputStream.close();
        dos.flush();
        dos.close();

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();

        if (getActivity()!=null)
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,
                            "Uh Oh! Error occured. Please try later", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();
                }
            });

        Log.d("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
    } catch (final Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        if (getActivity()!=null)
            getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext,
                            "Uh Oh! Error occured. Please try later",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        Log.d("Upload file to server Exception",
                "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    return serverResponseCode;
}
```

The control goes to the 2nd `catch` block. I have replaced the URL_HERE to my url. I am calling this `uploadFile()` method in an async task. I have done the same method to another of my APIs too. It works fine over there. But here, it gives an error. What wrong am I doing here?

Message from Logcat :

Exception : http://samaya.apprikart.com/dd_api_v1/report_news/
                                                                                 java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://samaya.apprikart.com/dd_api_v1/report_news/
                                                                                     at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:194)
                                                                                     at com.TheFryingPan.fragments.AddRecipeFragment.uploadFile(AddRecipeFragment.java:735)
                                                                                     at com.TheFryingPan.fragments.AddRecipeFragment$SubmitToServer.doInBackground(AddRecipeFragment.java:520)
                                                                                     at com.TheFryingPan.fragments.AddRecipeFragment$SubmitToServer.doInBackground(AddRecipeFragment.java:495)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
                                                                                     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:838)

Comment: Please show your url. And post the message from the logcat.

Comment: Which response code do you get?

Comment: You could add a dos.flush();

Comment: I have added the exception. Response code 400. It says bad request. How can I see what is going to the server?

Comment: I have done dos.flush(); after my fileInpustStream is closed.

Comment: I tried `SimpleMultiPartRequest` from DWorks/VolleyPlus. It works and gets posted. But through HTTPUrlconnection it doesnt work.

Comment: So you are posting a file to the server?

Comment: Yes I need to upload an imageFile

Comment: You should flush() before you ask for a response code. And dont close() the stream.

Comment: `filename=\""+ mSelectedImagePath`. You should supply a file name only. Not a file path. And why not use sourceFile.getName()?

Comment: You are not only posting a file. You post a news_title parameter too.

Comment: Yes. Like I have mentioned I am posting an image and few other details as parameters. I have included only one parameter i.e. title.

Comment: No you did not mention at all that you posted an image and or parameters. You did not supply relevant info to begin with.

Comment: But I have mentioned it above the code.

Comment: Sorry for not reading that.